# solder not sticking/board question

Tags: soldering

So I am pretty new to soldering and have recently started modding controllers. When I was trying to resolder a stick box back to the board, the solder was not sticking to a few pins. On those pins I noticed they were missing some metal on the board 
[image]

I was basically wondering what type of metal that is to get the solder to stick, and if I can repair the parts missing said metal.

Thanks so so much for looking at my post!

-back ground information- 
During my attempts my solder pen was on the hottest setting and I was also using Flux. Every open spot that does have the metal ring I have 0 issues to get the solder to stick so I am pretty sure that's what's wrong.

Comment: Basically, Image shows that solder pad itself is gone. I 2would still find out the connections and figure out another talking point, and go for jumpers

Comment: The super-cheap brown (paper-based phenolic, generically) laminate often will allow the pads to be lifted if you look crosswise at it, extreme care and good tools are called for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The brown stuff you're seeing on the right side is the bare circuit board -- the copper has been completely torn (or burnt) away from that pad.

There is, generally speaking, no way to repair pads that have been destroyed to this degree. Typically, you will need to find another point on the board that's part of the same circuit net and run a wire to it.

In this case, however, I suspect that the missing pad is not part of the circuit at all -- that pad looks like it is simply used as a mechanical "anchor" for the joystick. If this is the case, you may be able to leave that pin unconnected, or use a standard adhesive (like epoxy) to help hold the joystick in place.

To avoid this problem in the future, turn down the temperature on your soldering iron. Don't set it any higher than needed to melt your solder.

Comment: yup, thats been de-padded... PITA when it happens :(

Comment: Alright, thank you so much for your reply! I will definitely start being more careful when desoldering. If I had another board that was just completely dead that I no longer have a use for, could I perhaps tear the copper pads off that and use them to repair a damaged one? If so what would be the best way to go about it?

Comment: @Ciezi Unlikely. The copper is extremely thin (typically 35 microns), and will probably not survive being removed from the board. Nor is there any practical way to reattach it

Comment: Darn. Maybe I'll give it a try anyway. Not like I have anything to lose at this point. I appreciate all the help!

Answer (score 0):

alternative   is  to clean the  metal  and  use conductive adhesive  -  its whatever  gets it to work . Looked it up on ebay  say $2  -  its silver and yo  get  0.2 ml  -   0.2   of cubic centimeter

Comment: Conductive adhesive would not help as there is no metal left to clean. If the solder pads were still there, cleaning them would allow soldering which would be far better.